# How to download and install the 32feet.net api

Tags: c#, api, bluetooth, 32feet

I have downloaded the 32feet.net api but I am still not able to develop for Bluetooth in C#.

Some InTheHand.dll files are still missing and I don't find it in my directory. I guess I am doing it wrong but I don't know what.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: It's available via NuGet package manager (32feet.NET.Phone or 32feet.NET) -- that's the easiest way to ensure you're getting everything.

Comment: This was the small hint that I needed. It works fine now after using the NuGet package manager over Visual Studio. Thank you!

Comment: I've added an answer reflecting my comment since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's available via `NuGet package manager` (32feet.NET.Phone or 32feet.NET) -- that's the easiest way to ensure you're getting everything.